# Finding sequence in a set $A$ that tends to $\sup A$

Tags: analysis

I have been reading the book at http://www.neunhaeuserer.de/short.pdf, and have noticed that in the proof of the intermediate value theorem (Theorem 5.8 in the book), it seems to be quietly assumed that you can always find a sequence of points in a set that tend to the supremum of the set (in $\mathbb{R}$).

I presume this is true, but how would one go about proving it? I can't seem to find the result easily, but maybe I'm searching the wrong. What does one call this property (of there being a sequence converging to you?). It seems "limit point" would be the natural term, but I've discovered that the definition doesn't quite mean that--e.g. an isolated point $a$ cannot be limit point, but the sequence $a,a,a,a,a,a \dots$ converges to it (or is that a matter of how we define convergence?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of the Axiom of Countable Choice, which the author is taking for granted (actually, the author is taking stronger assumptions for granted, based on section 6 of the book).

The idea is as follows:

> If $\xi\in A$, then there is a constant sequence of points of $A$ converging to $\xi$. Otherwise, since $\xi$ is the supremum of $A$, then for each positive integer $n$, we have that $A\cap[\xi-\frac1n,\xi)$ is non-empty, and we simultaneously choose $x_n\in A\cap[\xi-\frac1n,\xi)$ for each such $n$. This gives us a sequence of points of $A$ converging to $\xi$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I don't think you really need an axiom of countable choice: suppose there's no sequence that tends to $\sup A$, then $\exists \epsilon >0$ such that $A \cap (\sup A-\epsilon,\sup A + \epsilon)=\emptyset$. This is an absurd since it will give you that $\sup A-\epsilon/2$ is an upper bound for A, violating the minimality of $\sup A$.

Comment: You need the axiom of choice. It is consistent that there is a dense subset of the real numbers without a countably infinite subset. Given a bounded subset of that set, how will you construct a sequence (which itself is a countable subset) attending its supremum?

Comment: I think that the axiom of determinacy should be enough

Comment: The axiom of determinacy implies countable choice for sets of real numbers. In particular it implies that there is no infinite Dedekind-finite sets of real numbers. Not to mention that the axiom of determinacy is a vastly stronger assumption that the axiom of choice (in terms of consistency strength) and requires a different form of justification. Finally, the common mathematical foundations nowadays is $\sf ZFC$ rather than $\sf ZF+AD$, so assuming $\sf AD$ is fine and all, but not fully compatible with the common assumptions for non-set theoretical foundations.

Comment: Suppose no sequence of points of $A$ tends to $\sup A$. That means that for any *given sequence* of points $x_n$ of $A$, there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that infinitely-many $x_n<\sup A-\epsilon$. Equivalently, every sequence of points of $A$ has a subsequence that is bounded away from $\sup A$. But this bound is dependent on the sequence, so we cannot conclude from this that $A$ is bounded away from $\sup A$. Indeed, as @Asaf points out, there need be no sequence of distinct points of $A$ at all, so that we can't necessarily draw any conclusions about $A$ from this.

Comment: I should also add that saying "I think that X should be enough" usually implies that X is weaker than the stated assumption. The axiom of determinacy is very not weaker than the axiom of countable choice. If one assumes $V=L(\Bbb R)$ then $\sf ZF+AD$ proves $\sf DC$ which in turn is stronger than the axiom of countable choice.

Answer (score 0):

Very astute question. Provided you discard the constant sequence (and, I guess, eventually constant sequences), limit point is the right notion in reasonable spaces. Assuming that $\sigma=\sup A$ is *not* an element of $A$, you are guaranteed for each $n$ an element $a_n\in A$ with $0<\sigma-a_n<1/n$.